# Anti-aliasing management in Java FX

Tags: java, javafx, antialiasing

I am implementing a professional software using `JavaFX 2.0 (JDK 1.8)` and I've got some image rendering problems in my toolbar.

The ImageView on a toolbar button resizes when `mouse hovers` him. It raises a problem when this image contains narrow letters :

- [image: Button graphic while un-hovered]
- [image: Button graphic while hovered]

The "little" image seems easier to read than the big one and preserves the original image's letter spacing, so my question is: is it possible to choose and custom anti-aliasing mode (`FXAA`, `SMAA`, etc.) for an ImageView? To add a constraint, I cannot enhance the toolbar height.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the [Scene constructors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Scene.html#Scene-javafx.scene.Parent-double-double-boolean-javafx.scene.SceneAntialiasing-) accepts a parameter of type [SceneAntialiasing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/SceneAntialiasing.html) which gives you 2 options:

- SceneAntialiasing.BALANCED (Enables anti-aliasing optimizing for a balance of quality and performance)
- SceneAntialiasing.DISABLED (Disables anti-aliasing)

As far as I know, those are the only 2 options you have.

Comment: Too bad, Swing seemed to be a little bit more complete for that.